# Converting table to JSON in Powerquery

Tags: powerquery, excel-2016

Context: Using Powerquery in Excel 2016 (Get & Transform) to receive data from a REST API which only accepts content-type: application/json. The content for HTTP POST request is stored in an excel table, which is to be converted to JSON for POST content.

If I use the following example from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt637075.aspx:

```
Request = Text.FromBinary(Json.FromValue([A={1, true, "3"}, B=#date(2012, 3, 25)]))
```

It returns the error:

```
Expression error: The name 'Json.FromValue' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.
```

Is it possible that the version of Powerquery in-built in Excel 2016 is missing this function? If so, is there another way of transforming the data to JSON in Powerquery?

Comment: Do you have the latest update for Excel 2016? What version of Power Query is running? You can check this from New Query | Query Options and going to the Diagnostics tab.

Comment: Version is 2.24.4065.1401

Comment: It works in Power BI which has Power Query version 2.36.4434.362 64 bit (June, 2016)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update Excel 2016. The latest update has Json.FromValue.

Comment: That did the trick. For those interested, you do not need a Office 365 subscription for this update. It is included in [KB3115139](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3115139). After applying the update, my Power Query version within Excel is 2.33.4337.481